# What is the use of callParent

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have gone through this [online tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-5/) to understand basic concepts of Sencha touch. Now, I am sure that I can look forward to begin coding for the real project with my knowledge.

But I have a question about the functionality of `this.callParent(arguments)` used by the Author in the tutorial.

I know the name clearly indicates that the **"parent class of *this* is being called"**.

But I have questions like: (*related to the tutorial*)

- Why we are calling the parent class?
- Will this run the parent class again completely?

Please help me to understand `callParent` related to the above tutorial.

I have gone through the [touch docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callParent) which I can't understand. (The explanation  seems completely different to me with respect to the Author's code).

[**Project download link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jdmdq6ipi3ksfu/NotesApp.rar)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question `this.callParent(arguments)` calls the appropriate function in the super class.

That is Calling `this.callParent(arguments)` in a constructor calls the constructor of the super class that is being extended.

**In the tutorial you mentioned, This is what the Author doing.**

```
launch: function () {
  //This line simply calls the super class(Ext.app.Controller) launch function  
  this.callParent(arguments);
  var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");
  notesStore.load();
  console.log("launch");
},

 init: function () {
  // This line simply calls the super class(Ext.app.Controller) init function   
  this.callParent(arguments); 
  console.log("init");
 }
```

But why he doing this, I am not sure because there is no need to call `Ext.app.Controller` class `init` and `launch` function in that tutorial.

**Let me explain with example**

1) Creating super class called `Main`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    launch: function () {
       console.log("Main launch");
    },      

    init: function () {
       console.log("Main init");
    },    

    config: {

    } 
});
```

2) Create subclass `SubMain` that extends `MyApp.controller.Main`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SubMain', {
    extend: 'MyApp.controller.Main',

    launch: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
       console.log("launch");
    },

     init: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
       console.log("init");
     },

    config: {
    }
});
```

Now when you run your application, the  console.log we placed in both super and subclass will print following in browser console

**Output**

```
Main init 
Main init 
SubMain init 
Main launch 
Main launch
SubMain launch
```

As we know that when we launch application `init` and `launch` function of every controller will be invoked once.

But, you see Main init & Main launch function is called twice, Why?

The reason it's called init and launch function of super class again is because of we placed `this.callParent(arguments);` in `init and launch` function of `SubMain`, that is calling init and launch function of `Main`(super class) class once again.

**There is more, What about `arguments` which passed in `callParent` function**

[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is a special parameter.

Now, let us take an example to test

```
Ext.define('Mail.controller.Messages', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            viewer: 'messageviewer',
            messageList: 'messagelist'
        },
        control: {
            messageList: {
                itemtap: 'loadMessage'
            }
        }
    },

    loadMessage: function(item) {
        this.getViewer().load(item);
    }
});
```

`Mail.controller.phone.Messages` class extends `Mail.controller.Messages`, this simply means all the configuration and functions are inherited.

```
 Ext.define('Mail.controller.phone.Messages', {
    extend: 'Mail.controller.Messages',

    config: {
        refs: {
            main: '#mainPanel'
        }
    },

    loadMessage: function(item) {
        // Without this line loadMessage function of super class will not be invoked
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.getMain().setActiveItem(1);
    }
});
```

Now when the user tabs on a item in `messageList` the `loadMessage` function in `Mail.controller.phone.Messages` class will be invoked.

Also we placed `this.callParent(arguments);` at `loadMessage` function, so first `Mail.controller.Messages` class `loadMessage` function will be invoked and then `this.getMain().setActiveItem(1);` line will run.

As mentioned earlier `loadMessage` function in `Mail.controller.Messages` will not be invoked until you place `this.callParent(arguments);` in `loadMessage` function at `Mail.controller.phone.Messages` class.

Note that `item` argument will be only passed to `loadMessage` function of `Mail.controller.phone.Messages`, but `loadMessage` function of `Mail.controller.phone.Messages` still gets the `item` argument, How ?

It's Because of `arguments` you passed in `this.callParent` function within `loadMessage` function of `Mail.controller.phone.Messages` class.

Comment: "The reason it's called init and launch function of super class again is because of we placed this.callParent(arguments); in init and launch function of SubMain, that is calling init and launch function of Main(super class) class once again." 
You wanted to explain simple, but you did not explained why it was called twice. Is this a original behaviour, that init (and launch) of parent is by default always called before child's init? Even if such behaviour is not specified by developer?